# What's the best way to implement AutoComplete in the server?

Tags: database, performance, optimization, autocomplete, full-text-search

This question is easy people. Make autocomplete beautiful in the client side of a web app is simple. There are a lot of plugins.

But, in the backside, in the server side, what's the best way to do it? I don't like the idea to hit the DB with each keypressed by the user.

I've been thinking about sphinx, or some full-text search engine running parallel from your site.

For example, if i have a PHP (high traffic) web site, i can create a parallel python script that get http requests from my "autocomplete textboxes". Then, when a user is pressing a key in the client side, the AJAX requests are directed to that python script that can use a special strategy.

What's your aproach?

Some conventions:

- Try not to hit the DB. I mean, get
  the request and do something SELECT *
  FROM foo WHERE bar LIKE "req%" is not
  a good answer. It may be a good
  strategy, but i know how to do it.*
- Replicated data can be a good choice.

Comment: You seem to have some unstated assumptions about the languages and technologies available on the server side. It would be easier to give a cogent reply if you would state them.

Comment: How big is the set of candidate strings? What criteria are used to rank them (i.e. same for everyone, per-user or even per-request criteria)?

Comment: @bmargulies I'm trying to focus on Architecture. But, as a guide. The "search framework" (for example Lucene, Sphinx, Memcache, whatever) can be whatever thing that can be installed on a Linux Server. Then, about languages, if it's a wide adopted framework, it will have libraries, but can consider good languages: Java, Phython, PHP.

Comment: @Ian Mackinnon Good question. It's a small dataset (for example all the keywords of a site) and is relatively static. Don't understand the "rank criteria" thing.

Comment: @santiago, by ranking I mean how you order the list of suggestions to the user. Eg. "alphabetically" would be the same for all users, "most recently searched for by this user" would be an example of a per-user, per-request ranking.

Comment: @Ian Great! I've not thought about that. It's a good idea. Thanks!!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I do agree that you need to have some better solution. [Apache solr](http://lucene.apache.org/solr/) has a "suggestion" feature that you can use pretty well. If your data set is small then put all the data in memory and just do a simple loop.

On the front end, I recommend using setTimeout() to wait for about 200ms before firing the ajax call. If in that 200ms, another keystroke is triggered, then cancel the last timeout and start another one. This is a really clean solution where it wouldn't hit the db with each keystroke. I have used it in the past and it works really well.

This explains solr with jquery and how to create an autocomplete really well.
http://www.mattweber.org/2009/05/02/solr-autosuggest-with-termscomponent-and-jquery/

Comment: Here is an article that I used in the past http://www.sematext.com/products/autocomplete/index.html

Comment: Really Really (loop it 1000 times) great. Thank you very much. I'll take it a look.

Answer (score 0):

You say in the comments that "It's a small dataset" of key words. Thus, it might be appropriate to have the client request the whole list as soon as the user starts typing into the field, then have the JavaScript respond to changes in user input on the client side.

That's one server hit per field per page (and only if the user types in the field), and you can cache it on the server so it rarely has to hit the DB.

**Edit:** Caching on the server is a big win because the list is the same for every request and for all users, but even better, this means you can cache the list in the client's browser by using an `Expires` or `Etag` header with a suitable period in the response. Thus the user can get unlimited autocompletion for just one (well-cached) server hit for the entire period of the browser cache.

Comment: Yes, i've thought about that. But that's not scalable. I mean, if something change in the future i can't keep loading all data in the client. Thanks anyway

Comment: @santiago, while considering scalability can be important, optimising for the known present makes a lot more sense than optimising for the unknown future :) Also I would argue that it is scalable to an extent; if the list becomes big enough start requesting all keywords that match the first letter, maybe later the first two letters, etc. Given that the overhead on each request is considerable, you may as well request a sizeable list of possibilities, rather than hitting the server every time a user pauses typing for a split-second.